# Composite foreign key design question

Tags: database-design

Suppose you have three tables, `t1`, `t2`, and `t3` with the following relational fields.

`t1`:

- `id` (PK)

`t2`: for good business reasons, `t2` has a composite primary key on `{t2.id, t1.id}`

- `id`
- `t1.id` (FK)

`t3`:

- `id` (PK)
- `t1.id`
- `t2.id`

The key relationship `t3` has is with `t2`. So, `t3` has a composite foreign key constraint on `{t1.id, t2.id}`.

**The question:** must `t1.id` in `t3` also be a foreign key? Why or why not?

My initial instinct is that of course, this additional FK is required. `t1.id` is the PK in `t1`, it must be a FK in `t3`. However I now believe it is not necessary because it does not add **any** information about the relationships between the three tables.

If `t2` had a simple primary key, of course there would be no reason to include `t1.id` in `t3`. From a relational standpoint, it is therefore sufficient for `t3` to reference `t2` via the composite FK.

Comment: Having a surrogate unique key in `t2` solves your problem nicely.

Comment: Errorneous scheme. Possible inconsistence. A record in `t3` may refer to one record in `t1` directly, and to another - via `t2`. One of 3 references must be removed in most cases. Of course there is a situation when such dualizm is correct, but these situations are too rare.

Comment: Nonsense. Your schema is just fine.